# Cant' install gulp

Tags: gulp

When I try to install gulp in my project repository, this message show:

> Error: Cannot find module 'clone' at Function.Module._resolveFilename
>   (module.js:325:15) at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25) at
>   Module.require (module.js:353:17) at require
>   (internal/module.js:12:17) at Object.
>   (C:\laragon\www\hms52\node_modules\laravel-elixir\node
>   _modules\gulp-util\node_modules\vinyl\index.js:2:13) at Module._compile (module.js:409:26) at Object.Module._extensions..js
>   (module.js:416:10) at Module.load (module.js:343:32) at
>   Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12) at Module.require
>   (module.js:353:17) at require (internal/module.js:12:17)

Comment: I've done that but when i run gulp again from command prompt, it shows 'can not find module escape-string-regexp'

Comment: `npm install --save escape-string-regexp`

Comment: Again it shows that I need other module. I install that module, it show I need another.